# asp.net file upload The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading

Tags: asp.net, large-file-upload

When I am trying to upload file of 32MB, firefox is showing following error on page.

" The connection was reset.
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."

I have tried foll. solutions -

1 .  in `<system.web>`

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000000" executionTimeout="999999"/>
```

2 .  in `<system.webserver>`

```
 <security>
  <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
 </security>
```

and

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" />
```

but still getting same error.
I think problem is related to "executionTimeout". Application is not setting this timeout for request.

Comment: Its working fine here on localhost but on clients server its not working. Client is having IIS 7.

Comment: What error code are your receiving? 404.XX?

Comment: @Blachshma: I can not reset webserver, Site is live. :( and I dont have access to do that. appreciating your help...

Comment: When you upload a 25 MB file, is it ok?

Comment: @Blachshma: 14MB file is uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally problem resolved...
We need to keep both tags in config file.
i.e.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000000" executionTimeout="999999"/>
```

and

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Actually I was commenting one line and testing with another. :)

Answer (score 2):

First: Notice that `maxRequestLength` is in KB whereas `maxAllowedContentLength` is in **bytes**
So you're just allowing 1MB... Increase your `maxAllowedContentLength`, for instance:

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000" />
```

Second: 
Try a higher execution time such as `executionTimeout="999999"`

Comment: maxRequestLength in KB and 40960 KB = 40 MB. I have set that to 1000000 i.e. 976 MB. i tried. Still getting same error.

Comment: Lets make this even simpler, please update the question with your CURRENT config, both system.web and system.webserver.

Comment: @Balchshma: I have tested in internet explorer and chrome as well.. not working.

Comment: Are you SURE you're updating the web.config which is in the ROOT directory of your application?!? Also, is it in the same directory into which you're trying to upload the file?

Comment: Since you've maxed the values and it should be fine. And you're saying you're sure the web.config is in the correct place. Without you having access to the IIS and/or running iisrest I'm afraid I can't help anymore..

Comment: @Abhi But one more tip - If you see the limit is ~30 MB, then since IIS 7 restricts by default maximum allowed content length for a request to 30 MB. It probably has something to do with settings on the IIS server, which doesn't let you override the `maxAllowedContentLength` value and you'll *need* access to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue and set:
`<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="999999"/>` inside  tag
in the web.config file.

if `maxRequestLength="2000000000"` does not support then use the range 0-2097151

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you have IIS7 you need to following code in config file.  <security>  <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000" />  </requestFiltering> </security>