# ASPX file upload error: The Connection to the server was reset

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, configuration-files

While this question [asp.net file upload The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934221/asp-net-file-upload-the-connection-to-the-server-was-reset-while-the-page-was-lo) refers to a solution I am looking for, it does not say where these new lines are to be added:

```
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000000" executionTimeout="999999"/>
```

Please let me know where these lines are to be added: is it the machine.config or web.config? I got 'unrecognised section error' in nearly every section I tried to add it to in web.config. I don't want to touch machine.config until I am sure. Thanks.

Comment: httpRuntime is a part of web.config system.web section and security is part of system.webserver i assume you have to create it if using empty web.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Web.Config`, it needs to be added in following format :

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpRuntime>
```

Example :

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000000" executionTimeout="999999"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

For more information, you can read the article : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.71).aspx